# Wordpress city locator code woo-commerce. My question is different I need city locator not store locator

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

The purpose of this city locator is to locate where the customer has made an order I meant a particular city they have ordered.

Objective requirements: Needs to get the customer city and after the payment and order did. the city should be added in the order history to know where the order from.

I have tried a few plugins but it is not working.

Comment: Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to learn how to create a minimal, reproducible question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a city locator?

The city data can be fetched from Billing /shipping address of the order.

Is there any specific purpose? If yes, please give more idea so that we may help

Comment: I need to know a specific item is ordered from a particular city. if they picked the city that will be carried throughout the billing and shipping process we will get to know where the order from.

Answer (score 0):

Please use GeoIP Detection Plugin of wordpress. Alternatively,in PHP we can easily get the users IP address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] option. However, you may not get location details.

To get location detail from IP address, you may take help from 3rd party websites like http://www.snoopi.io/ or http://www.ipstack.com/